# Flutter List View automatically scroll to the top with big item

Tags: android, flutter, listview

I'm using flutter 3.0.1,

I want to make a big scrollable list view with a lot of items. And then, automatically scroll to one element. I know how to do it, but I'm having trouble with the big list.

I've made a video of my problem. https://youtube.com/shorts/ekvsMC8Azrc

In the video you can see that I have a lot of big containers with different colors. So I'm scrolling down (a lot) And then later when I want to scroll back to the top, All the containers show up fast and I'm near the top.

In the code I just have a `ListView.builder` with a list of container with different size and just a random color. I've try `cacheExtent` but I don't know how to use it.

```
ListView.builder(
    cacheExtent: 1000,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, int index) {
      return allContainer[index];
    },
    itemCount: allContainer.length,
  ),
```

So I want to know if there's a way to scroll up normally? Because I want to replace the container with big image, but when I scroll to the top it's ugly and not user friendly.

The other solution that I have it's to use `SingleChildScrollView` but it's not optimised and I can't directly scroll to a specific item. Do you have a solution?

EDIT: I add my StatefulWidget

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:manga/widget/center_circular_indicator.dart';

class WeirdListView extends StatefulWidget {
  const WeirdListView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _WeirdListViewState createState() => _WeirdListViewState();
}

class _WeirdListViewState extends State<WeirdListView> {
  Future<Widget> getImage(int i) async {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Container(
      color: Color((Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt()).withOpacity(1.0),
      // child: imageW,
      width: width,
      height: Random().nextInt(10000) + 5000,
    );
  }

  List<Widget> getAllImage() {
    List<Widget> allPages = [];
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
      allPages.add(FutureBuilder(
          future: getImage(i),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Widget> text) {
            return text.data ?? const CenterCircularProgressIndicator();
          }));
    }
    return allPages;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> allImages = getAllImage();
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        cacheExtent: 1000,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, int index) {
          return allImages[index];
        },
        itemCount: allImages.length,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The function getImage actually add the image in the container.

Comment: Can you include a full widget that will reproduce the same issue

Comment: The item height is too big, I don't see any issue after testing your snippet, on web except `FutureBuilder`

Comment: I know the item height is too big. But I need to show a lot of image with a very big height and they need to be stick and we can scroll

Answer (score 1):

You should pass your own [ScrollController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController-class.html), this object controlls how a Scrollable widget behave.

So you should pass it to your ListView like that

```dart
ListView.builder(
        contrller: _scrollController,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, int index) {
          return allImages[index];
        },
        itemCount: allImages.length,
      )
```

Then you can call the method `jumpTo` or `animateTo` on a button click for example to scroll to the top automatically.

Note that you can also use this with the `SingleChildScrollView` widget.

Comment: I know how to use the jumpTo. But here the problem is when I have a big ListView with big item there is a problem when I'm scrolling (see the video) when I scroll down a lot and then I scroll up a little bit I'm immediately to the top